# Using S3 instead of FTP- any reason NOT to?

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3

Whenever a client wants an FTP storage solution, my instinct it to direct them to S3 instead, as a secure and cost-effective alternative.  Is there any good reason NOT to use S3 instead of FTP/SFTP in any situation where you're setting someone up from scratch?

**EDIT:**
To clarify: Is there any capability of FTP/SFTP (Outside of setting it up on your own server) that would constitute a compelling reason to go with an FTP/SFTP solution over an S3 solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, from the way you've phrased the question, that there's an answer which would convince you to stick with FTP...

That said, if you had asked this a couple years ago I would have said a lack of quality clients relative to those for SFTP might have given me pause.

SFTP is about as secure as HTTPS, so I'm not sure security is a deciding factor.

Some corporations are paranoid about keeping their data on servers under their control; but you seem to be asking about setting up storage from scratch, so perhaps that is not a consideration.

Comment: I'd say the more relevant FTP clients these days usually have support for S3, so yeah the client question is no longer a deciding issue...

Comment: In most ways that matter, SFTP is _more_ secure than HTTPS. Keep in mind that SFTP is an entirely different protocol and not related to FTP in any way. FTPS is a FTP over SSL. SFTP is the SSH filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is a protocol and there are others you can use instead.  FTP is not secure at all and should only be used for publicly shared files and never private data.

I have gradually stopped using Amazon S3 in favour of [Rackspace Cloud Files](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud-hosting/cloud-products/cloud-files/), which is cheaper and the support is massively better.